# angular ng-click inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem to bind the `ng-click` directive with a method inside my controller. I have tried to put curly brackets inside `ng-click`, but with a syntax error. The same behavior occurs if I put `ng-click="{{action.method}}"`.

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.11" data-semver="1.2.11" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.11/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="Controller">
  <ul ng-repeat="action in actions">
    <li ng-click={{action.method}}>{{action.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

### controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('app',[])

app.controller('Controller',['$scope',function ($scope) 
{
  $scope.actions = [
    {
      name : 'add Folder',
      method : 'addFolder()'
    }  
  ]

  $scope.addFolder = function(){
    alert('addFolder')
  }
}])
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="action in actions" ng-click="action.method()">{{action.name}}</li>
  </ul>
```

instead.

Here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/cuye/2/edit

Note that `ng-click` accepts expression, not only function so you need to call it: `action.method()`.

Comment: +1 I'd add that the poster has a confusion about string interpolation vs expressions.  String interpolations use the {{}} delimiters and will evaluate to a string.  This is to be used in attributes that are one-way string bindings ('@').  The `ng-click` is a function binding ('?') which takes an expression, similar to two-way object bindings ('=').

Comment: @BrianGenisio , you have reason about my confusion , the problem was simple but i'm pretty new in angularjs ,I've done enough stupid mistake. Thank you both for your help.